# Item Adding in event receiver sharepoint 2010

Tags: c#, sharepoint, sharepoint-2007, event-receiver

```
 public override void ItemAdding(SPItemEventProperties properties)
       {
           base.ItemAdding(properties);
           SPItem itemBeingAdded = properties.ListItem;
           var startTime = itemBeingAdded["Start Time"];
           // Some code goes here.
       }
```

I am firing this event while adding an item in a calender list. It is getting fired. No problem. But I am not getting any value from `properties`. In the above code `startTime` gives me nothing. Actually, I want to access the column field of the item (`properties` in my case) is being added.

[image]

When the user will click in save button, How can I get the column value in code behind (Inside the `ItemAdding(SPItemEventProperties properties) method`). Let say, I need `Start Time` and `End Time` to compare them with some other values. Problem is in the `ItemAdding` method. ItemUpdating is working fine.

```
public override void ItemUpdating(SPItemEventProperties properties)
       {

           base.ItemUpdating(properties);
           SPItem itemBeingAdded = properties.ListItem;
           var startTime = itemBeingAdded["Start Time"];
       }
```

Comment: Did you inspect the contents of `SPItemEventProperties`? Is there an entry with the `"Start Time"` key? The internal names of fields may be different from what's displayed in the form.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I am going to try with internal name.

Comment: Result is same as before. Internal name is not working also.

Comment: Did you inspect the contents of `SPItemEventProperties` using your debugger's [watch capability](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0taedcee.aspx)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally, I got my answer from [here](http://srisharepointdevelopment.blogspot.com/2013/06/beforeproperties-and-afterproperties-in.html). The way would be like following

```
string message = properties.AfterProperties["Description"].ToString();
```

Another thing is you should use internal name. For my case, display name didn't work.